# List is not modified, multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to figure out how to properly modify a list in multiprocessing using Python. I have written a toy code:

```
 input_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
  
  manager = Manager()
  shared_list = manager.list()
  shared_list = input_list[:]
  
  
  def do_stuff(element, i):
      global shared_list
      shared_list[i] = element[i] * 2
      print(shared_list[i])
  
  
  processes = []
  for i in range(len(input_list)):
      p = Process(target=do_stuff, args=(input_list, i))
      p.start()
      processes.append(p)
  
  for p in processes:
      p.join()
  
  print(shared_list)
```

I had created a shared list by means of `Manager` and subsequently I tried to utilize it inside the `do_stuff` function. The problem is that once the multiprocessing is over, `shared_list` is not modify. Could you please help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
shared_list = input_list[:]
```

With this statement, you are *replacing* the value of `shared_list` with the value of `input_list[:]` (that is, you are discarding your `manager.list` instance).

You're probably looking for:

```
shared_list[:] = input_list[:]
```

By using a slice assignment like this, you are setting the *contents of* `shared_list` to the contents of `input_list`. This is called "slice assignment" and there are a variety of tutorials out there that discuss it in more detail.

Comment: alternatively, just do `shared_list = manager.list(input_list)` to have the manager's list initialized with the values you want